# Cant see results of digitaly signed hash C#

Tags: c#

everybody!

I'm trying to digitally sign some data in C#. Everything goes without error but when I want to see the results of RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash , I get some strange results.

Here's My code:

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "SOME NAME", true);

    X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = certCollection.GetEnumerator();

    X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()){
       x509 = enumerator.Current;
    }

    store.Close();

    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
    csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PrivateKey;

    if (csp == null){
        throw new Exception("Valid certificate was not found");
    }      

    string sTestText = "SomeTestData";
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();  

    SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
    ASCIIEncoding encoding2 = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding2.GetBytes(sTestText);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

    Byte[] baSignedHash = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));

    string sSignedHash = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(baSignedHAsh);

    Console.WriteLine("sSignedHash=" + sSignedHash );
```

I get this text:
sSignedHash=?H↨???C↑?X        !??????sPotpisaniHash=J1??Q????7 ?G??D?5?=Dc?6C????♀??j?p?♠?♥?{♫??[i?↔?????◄??;?‼?????}Sx☺>VN?i6?☻'??▲f??t@?E?↕?▬??►k??v?'???☻ GX??}x@???)??F?7TP?♂&??

I've tried different encodings(UTF8, ect) but no luck. Does enyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does enyone know what could be the problem?

Yes. You're trying to treat opaque binary data as if it were text. It's not.

You could get a hex representation:

```
string text = BitConverter.ToString(baSignedHash);
```

Or a base-64 representation:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(baSignedHash);
```

It's very important to understand the difference between "binary data which is actually encoded text data" (which is where `Encoding.GetString` comes in) and "binary data which isn't text" (e.g. image data, executable files, encrypted data, compressed data).

Comment: Thanks Jon. It really helped. Now I get the difference. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any text encoding, since a hash does not represent any text. It's just a bunch of bytes.

You should use either hex encoding, or Base64 encoding to transform the hash into something readable.

Hex has the advantage that each byte of the hash, corresponds to two characters of the output.

```
string sSignedHash = BitConverter.ToString(baSignedHash).Replace("-", "");
```

Base64 has the advantage that it's shorter.

```
string sSignedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(baSignedHash);
```

---

To encode the input text, I recommend using `new Utf8Encoding(false, true)`. This does not emit a BOM, and it throws an exception when it encounters invalid input, instead of silently outputting corrupt data.